# Меняется позиция обьектов в unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет! Делая игру в unity, я столкнулся с проблемой изменения позиции объектов. Я делаю простую игру крестики-нолики, на сцене за кадром расположены непосредственно image, перемещаю одним скриптом с помощью GameObject.transform.position = new Vector2(x, y); Позиция в сцене не меняется при изменении разрешения, но визуально выглядит по другому. Так как хочу играть в эту игру не один, а может и выложить в гугл плей, то хотелось бы, чтобы на всех экранах игра не отличалась. В скриптах не может быть проблем, позиция одна и та же при разных разрешениях в редакторе.
build settings
[[image: build settings]]
настройки камеры
[image: настройки камеры]
в редакторе unity
[image: в редакторе unity]
в игре(разрешение монитора 2560x1440)
[1][image: в игре(разрешение монитора 2560x1440)]

Comment: Возможно ваши крестики и нолики - это UI объекты (Image) и вы забыли настроить им якоря (беленькие такие). Вообще игра не должна быть на канвасе и лучше это делать через SpriteRenderer (хотя я не знаю, как вы делаете)

Comment: благодарю, сделал, всё заработало